# Is it possible to use Microsoft Graph to search an entire organization's email database instead of just one user's?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was looking through Microsoft Graph's API documentation for mail and noticed all of the routes were user oriented. They required you to have a user in mind and from there, you could search that specific user's emails.

However, I'm trying to search my entire organization's email database using various filters. Is that possible without enumerating every user and searching each of them individually? It seems like I would hit a rate limit very quickly with that approach. If not, what other approaches are there to this problem?

Comment: Would [EWS SearchMailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/searchmailboxes-operation) work for you? In Graph there's no option to do so as far as I'm concerned. Of course there's always [Search-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet but I assume you want to find any alternative.